# Suggestions on how to build a library that can be used in many of my applications

Tags: c++, c

In the past I have created a jar file that contained many "**helper functions**" that I used and made common to many different applications. I felt this was important as anytime I used my **"helper" jar file** in any new applications or when making changes to any existing ones, the latest and most up to date version of my **"helper" jar** was always used. It was developed separately and had it's own version control.

I'm looking to do something similar with C/C++

At the moment I have a collection of headers, doing something similar to my **"helper" jar** in java but finding it cumbersome managing changes, ensuring the most up to date collections are used. So for example, if I made some changes to these **"helper"** headers, I need to copy them into each project and rebuild.

If we take the below as an example of what I do in Java;

[image]

and the below is the structure that I'd like to do something similar with in C++;

[image]

I'd like some way of keeping **my_includes** separate so that any changes I made to **my_includes** are automatically included in any existing or new applications, in the way **Utilities.jar** is in the above Java example

I accept that I cant build a library or such as it won't then be as portable, **right?**

I suspect I'm missing something quite obvious, **just not to me.**

All helpful comments appreciated, thanks in advance...

Comment: Just pass the include path stored outside your project in the compiler settings?

Comment: You're not missing anything obvious -- this situation is _much_ harder to handle neatly in C than in Java. Java JARs are generally self-contained, but C libraries usually require a mix of binaries and source headers. Keeping them coordinated when you have multiple versions requires being highly systematic. If there's a nice, automated way to do this, I'd like to know about it too.

Answer (score 0):

At first you could create a library from your utilitis.cpp and all include files independently and add this library to any project. I just provide URL for sample generate the static and shared library.

[Create static and shared library (GCC)](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/languages/C-C-plus-plus/GCC/create-libraries/index)

And then you can add custom include files to any project in c++ just  need to add the specific directories to  your include Path in compile time base your platform or if you use  cmake you can edit the "include_directories". And also you should link the generated library to your project as described in provided URL.